# Footer ain't at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my footer to the bottom of page.
When I create a fiddle it works; https://jsfiddle.net/3dd73cuk/
But on my page it´s "flying"; http://bjornc.se/sites/torhultsbrunn/
I guess bootstrap has some default behavior that messes it up?!

**Code**

```
<style>
    .footer{
        background-image: url("img/grassTop.png");
        background-size: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Torhults Brunn.se</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Om oss</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Våra tjänster</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="lead">Trädgårdsmöbler</p>
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Trämöbler</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Metallmöbler</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Konstrottingmöbler</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Parasoll & Övrigt</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dynor</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">

            <div class="row carousel-holder">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>

                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/drommingeSoffa.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/durbanKonstRottingGrupp.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/nydalaGrupp.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/shabbyGrupp.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/sodertorpSoffaByggbar.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/tannoHammock.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="img/carousel/torpetTradgardsgrupp.png" style="height: 300px" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">First Product</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">Second Product</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">Third Product</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">Fourth Product</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">Fifth Product</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <h4><a href="#">Like this template?</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>If you like this template, then check out <a target="_blank" href="http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-1-building-a-review-system/">this tutorial</a> on how to build a working review system for your online store!</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-1-building-a-review-system/">View Tutorial</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<hr>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="footer">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>Copyright &copy; Torhultsbrunn 2015</p>
        </div>

</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Its not floating it is fixed but your middle content is getting overlapped. Try    position:absolute on container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `shop-homepage.css` you have this:

```
margin: 50px 0;
```

That's what's causing it to "fly" since it's applying a margin to it which forces it up, even though you have `bottom: 0;` present, but since you are including the `shop-homepage.css` afer your `bootstrap.min.css` it's overwriting the previous `.footer`.

Simply change it to:

```
margin: 0px 0;
```